# Find self-avoiding-filling-polygon represented by system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory, polygons

In Euclidean graph where each vertex is a point on the $2D$ plane, so the weight of each edge is the Euclidean distance between the vertices. I want to find self-avoiding-filling-polygon from my graph vertices. Or in other words, a path that visit each vertex exactly once and returning to the starting position without intersecting itself on the way.

I wrote this [pseudo code](http://tsp-vs-world.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/big-plane.html) that is doing the job in $O(N^2)$, I want to know if using system of linear equations to represent my graph will provide me a better way finding my polygon?

Answer (score 1):

Note that regions you specify using linear inequalities are necessarily convex: so unless you are OK with visiting only the convex hull of (some subset of) the vertices, I don't think that is the way to go for this problem.

How about an edge-flipping approach? Draw any random path that visits all of the vertices (but perhaps self-intersects). Then detect if two edges intersect, and if so, swap their endpoints so that they no longer do (i.e., turn `X` into `||` or `=`, whichever doesn't disconnect the graph.) Repeat until no edges intersect. I'm not sure off-hand if this approach always terminates, but maybe you can think along these lines.

Comment: Edge-flipping approach is what my pseudo code do, the problem is that it takes is to long. I am trying to find a shortcut.

Comment: Edge-flipping terminates because it strictly shortens the path

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah, good observation.