# Calculate self-avoiding-filling-polygons

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polygons

### Definition of self-avoiding-filling-polygon

In Euclidean graph where each vertex is a point on the $2D$ plane, so the weight of each edge is the Euclidean distance between the vertices. **Self-avoiding-filling-polygon** will be a path that visit each vertex exactly once and returning to the starting position without intersecting itself on the way.

How to calculate how many such polygons could be?

**Methods to create such polygons could be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547919/101178) and [here](http://tsp-vs-world.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/big-plane.html).*

Comment: What's the purpose of weight in this context?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen no point just to explain my graph, Euclidean part of my graph. Please edit it if can find a better explanation of the problem.